# Upstart to systemd conversion doesn't work for curl and watch?

Tags: upstart, systemd

I had this upstart job earlier:

```
description "This is Notification Service"
author "King"

start on runlevel [2345]
exec watch -n 1 /usr/bin/curl -s https://domain.com/cron >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Now, I've converted it to systemd:

```
[Unit]
Description=This is Notification Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/watch -n 1 /usr/bin/curl -s https://domain.com/cron >/dev/null 2>&1'


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But it is not working, it always fails when I start it.

```
● notify-fb.service - This is Notification Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/notify-fb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-09-25 02:25:02 PST; 3h 53min ago
  Process: 15299 ExecStart=/usr/bin/watch -n 1 /usr/bin/curl -s https://domain.com/cron (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 15299 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 25 02:25:02 xxxx.com systemd[1]: Started This is Notification Service.
Sep 25 02:25:02 xxxx.com watch[15299]: Error opening terminal: unknown.
Sep 25 02:25:02 xxxx.com systemd[1]: notify-fb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 25 02:25:02 xxxx.com systemd[1]: notify-fb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 25 02:25:02 xxxx.com systemd[1]: notify-fb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your output, there is:

> watch[15299]: Error opening terminal: unknown.

It looks like perhaps `watch` is expecting to connect to a TTY on STDOUT, but is failing. See the docs for [`StandardOutput=` in systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=) for options to set the TTY.

systemd can also replace the need to use "watch" completely. It appears that `watch` is simply calling the URL once per second. The same thing could be accomplished with a systemd timer. See `man systemd.timer` and `man systemd.time` to learn about systemd timers.